# 'Amcharts.isReady' is not working in angular6?

Tags: angular6, amcharts

I am using amchart in my angular6 app with the help of following tutorial

[amchart3-angular](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts3-angular2)

But I need to show the graph after loaded all it's properties.How can I check whether the graph is ready to load in angular6?I tried with 'isReady' property of amchart.But it shows following error.

```
Cannot read property 'isReady' of undefined
```

**app.component.ts**

```
chart: AmChart;
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.chart = this.AmCharts.makeChart('chartdiv', {
  'type': 'gauge',
  'theme': 'light',
  'dataProvider': [],
  'axes': [{
    'axisColor': 'transparent',
    'color': '#fff',
    'endValue': 7,
    'gridInside': true,
    'inside': true,
    'radius': '100%',
    'valueInterval': 1,
    'tickColor': '#fff',
    'pivotRadius': '0%',
    'id': 'axes1',
    'topText': 'RPM',
    'topTextFontSize': 9,
    'topTextYOffset': -20,
    'topTextColor': '#fff',
    'bottomTextYOffset': -3,
    'bottomTextColor': '#fff',
    'minorTickLength': 16,
    'tickLength': 22,
    'tickThickness': 2,
    'labelOffset': 5,
    'bands': [{
      'color': '#f91f1f',
      'endValue': 7,
      'innerRadius': '87%',
      'startValue': 5
    },
    {
      'color': '#e60000',
      'endValue': 0,
      'startValue': 0,
      'alpha': 0.3,
      'radius': '100%',
      'innerRadius': '15%',
    },
    {
      'color': '#e60000',
      'endValue': 0,
      'startValue': 0,
      'alpha': 0.6,
      'radius': '100%',
      'innerRadius': '15%',
    },
    ]
  }, {
    'axisColor': '#fff',
    'color': 'black',
    'axisThickness': 3,
    'endValue': 140,
    'radius': '45%',
    'valueInterval': 20,
    'tickColor': 'black',
    'axisAlpha': '0',
    'bottomText': 'km/h',
    'bottomTextFontSize': 9,
    'bottomTextYOffset': -15,
    'bottomTextColor': 'black',
    'labelOffset': 2,
    'tickThickness': 1.2,
    'bands': [{
      'color': '#fff',
      'alpha': 1,
      'startValue': 0,
      'endValue': 220,
      'radius': '100%',
      'innerRadius': '0'
    }]
  }],
  'arrows': [{
    'color': '#ff0000',
    'innerRadius': '6.3%',
    'radius': '40%',
    'startWidth': 3,
    'value': 0,
  }, {
    'color': '#ff0000',
    'innerRadius': '46%',
    'radius': '90%',
    'startWidth': 8,
    'value': 0
  },
  {
    'color': '#111',
    'innerRadius': '7%',
    'radius': '0',
    'startWidth': 0,
    'value': 0,
    'nailAlpha': 1,
    'nailRadius': 10
  }
  ],
  'export': {
    'enabled': true
  }
  });
 }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div id="chartdiv" [style.width.%]="100" [style.height.px]="400">
```

in the above code I created the chart and store it in a variable having type 'Amchart' and displayed it in template with the help of 'id'. When I run the app the chart take little amount of time to show it in template. So that I need to show the graph only after it's initialization.How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you provide a demo (e,g., using StackBlitz)?

Comment: @tilo i edited the question with the code.please check it.

Comment: Taking your example, I created a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iouzur 
Could you elaborate what is not working? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: How can I check graph is ready to load in angular? Ie,in javascript we can use 'isReady' property of amchart to check whether the chart is completed it's initialization.but  I failed to apply the same action in angular?

Comment: According to https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts3/issues/59#issuecomment-235078412 `AmCharts.makeChart()` handles checks for DOM readiness already

Comment: So how can I  write a if condition to check the chart is ready?

Comment: Depending on your use case, you could add a listener (Point 5 in your linked documentation) or use the update mechanism (Point 4 in the documentation)